# CSS textAlign Justify adds big trailing space at the buttom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

when i display text component and loads big text file in React native, and style it as

```
textAlign: "justify"
```

there is a very big space at the end of the text component

is there a solution or other technic to justify the displayed text left and right other than `textAlign: "justify"`

triming text using JS does not do the trick since CSS overrides Js function again

Comment: text align justify is generally considered bad practice, especially for small screen widths which I would expect to see a lot where react native is used

Comment: then what is the good practice to align text on both sides if needed,to fill text on both sides ?